# Plotly uirevision doesn't work on plotly.js-basic-dist-min?

Tags: reactjs, plotly, plotly.js

I'm trying to build Plotly chart where it shouldn't reset chart when dynamically adding data.
I'm using buddy.works as deploy engine and i have limited ram so had to use " plotly.js-basic-dist-min"
this is what I'm trying to achieve https://codepen.io/plotly/pen/ebMJEW .

but I'm facing problem while using dist-min version. as uirevision works fine on

```
import Plot from 'react-plotly.js';
```

but it doesn't work for

```
import createPlotlyComponent from "react-plotly.js/factory";
var Plotly = require('plotly.js-basic-dist-min')
```

Is there any other way? did i miss something? Thanks!

here's my full code

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import createPlotlyComponent from "react-plotly.js/factory";
var Plotly = require('plotly.js-basic-dist-min')


function App() {
  const Plot = createPlotlyComponent(Plotly);
  const [data, setData] = useState<any>({
    x:[],
    y:[],
    type:'scatter'
  })
  useEffect(()=>{
    let x:any=[]
    let y:any=[]
    let i=1;
    let inval = setInterval(()=>{
      x= [...x, i]
      y= [...y, Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1]
      setData({
        x:x,
        y:y,
        type:'scatter'
      })
      i++
    }, 5000)
    return ()=>{
      clearInterval(inval);
    }

  },[])
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Plot
          data={[data]}
          config={{ scrollZoom: false, responsive: true, displaylogo: false}}
          useResizeHandler={true}
          style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }} 
          
          layout={{
            title: 'User Zoom Persists<br>When uirevision Unchanged',
            uirevision:'true',
            xaxis: {autorange: true},
            yaxis: {autorange: true}
          }}
          
        />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

moving `const Plot = createPlotlyComponent(Plotly);` outside function fix it.